# Cambiar tamaño del select? No los elementos de la lista

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

No consigo cambiar el tamaño específicamente el `height` del `select`, ni si quiera dentro de un `container`, o un `div`.

Aqui os dejo un ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ejemplo select</title>

    <!-- CSS de Bootstrap -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Tema opcional -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .no-padding{
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 50px">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 activity-line-action-list no-padding">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-setting col-md-9">
                    <div style="position: relative" class="form-control-wrapper no-padding ">
                        <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control input-direccion" placeholder=""   >
                        <i class="icon-left  font-icon font-icon-pin icon-direccion input-tooltip">
                        </i>
                        <div class="form-tooltip-error" style="margin-bottom: -12px;right: 25px;display:none"> Incorrecta</div>
                        <span class="font-icon font-icon-star icon-rigth add-direccion-favorita "></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
                    <select class="zonal_select" placeholder="m">
                      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Librería jQuery requerida por los plugins de JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Editado:
Necesito que el `select` se vea en la misma posición en la misma linea, y con el mismo tamaño del `input` , pero no lo consigo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes ser mas especifico? a que quieres cambiarle la altura? al select?...

Comment: Viendo que usas Bootstrap, [la doc te explica como hacerlo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#sizing), por ejemplo: `<select class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <option>Large select</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control">
  <option>Default select</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm">
  <option>Small select</option>
</select>` ahí tienes varios tamaños.

Comment: Si pero es que no se porque, no consigo cambiarlo , no con css, ni height, ni padding, ni nada  no lo unico es con el webkit

Comment: En los `<link rel=...` aparece que estás usando (o intentando usar) Bootstrap. Verifica que se está incluyendo bien. Si usas esa librería será para aprovechar sus ventajas, entre las cuales se encuentra lo que quieres, aplicando una clase como esta al `select`: **`<select class="form-control form-control-lg">`**, donde `lg` indica un select grande y así sucesivamente.

Comment: El problema no es bootstrap, solo trate de replicar mi código original.

Comment: ¿Probaste un select como indicado más arriba en comentario? ¿Tampoco funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas espero esto sea lo que buscas lo único que tienes que hacer es al `select` ponerle la propiedad `height:50px` para ponerle la altura deseada

```css
.selectAltura {
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
}

.selectAltura2 {
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ejemplo select</title>

    <!-- CSS de Bootstrap -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Tema opcional -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .no-padding{
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 50px">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 activity-line-action-list no-padding">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-setting col-md-9">
                    <div style="position: relative" class="form-control-wrapper no-padding ">
                        <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control input-direccion" placeholder=""   >
                        <i class="icon-left  font-icon font-icon-pin icon-direccion input-tooltip">
                        </i>
                        <div class="form-tooltip-error" style="margin-bottom: -12px;right: 25px;display:none"> Incorrecta</div>
                        <span class="font-icon font-icon-star icon-rigth add-direccion-favorita "></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
                    <select  class="zonal_select selectAltura" placeholder="m">
                      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
                    <select  class="zonal_select selectAltura2" placeholder="m">
                      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Librería jQuery requerida por los plugins de JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está usando Bootstrap, es un contrasentido usar CSS para eso , cuando Bootstrap tiene maneras de hacerlo, de hecho, si usa esa biblioteca, supongo, es para aprovechar sus ventajas.

Comment: Claro pero este caso es solo para la prueba no se la agregaría a todos los `select `sino al deseado y la idea de usar una librería es ayudarte mas no hacer todo en ella si no te limitas

Comment: Por alguna razón no me funciona la etiqueta height, no cambia para nada nisiquera con !important

Comment: A ver, con Bootstrap, eso se haría agregando esta clase al `select`: `<select class="form-control form-control-lg">` lo que dices de que te limitas, es lo mismo, escribiendo CSS te limitas ¿no?, ademas de re-inventar la rueda, de sobrecargarte de código redundante, etc.

Comment: prueba con agregarle el `padding` al `select` a ver @EdwinCubillos

Comment: @A.Cedano, si con esa clase funciona, gracias, necesito estudiar más bootstrap, soy back.

Comment: y claro @A.Cedano tienes razón pero la librería no siempre te da todas las soluciones tienes que saber como hacer las cosas con las bases

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras, Gracias por tus respuesta, pero con css intente y no me sirve debe ser que tengo muchas cosas .

Comment: tienes una classe `.no-padding` prueba con quitársela y agregarle el `padding `

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @A.Cedano si bootstrap ofrece la solución se debe implementar hasta donde más se pueda, para eso se está importando la librería... obviamente puede que no tenga la solución a todo pero si a la gran mayoría de problemas que vayas a tener

Comment: Luis Daniel no digo que no haya que aprender las bases, pero eso no justifica tener una librería instalada para luego hacer uno mismo las cosas que dicha librería hace. Bootstrap existe precisamente para simplificar procesos como estos mediante la asignación de determinadas clases a los elementos... Entonces, usar CSS para esto teniendo Bootstrap es como tener un Mercedes e irte a pie a una ciudad de 100 o 500 km. Bueno sí, morirás en forma, apreciarás el recorrido, llegarás satisfecho de haber hecho tantos Km, pero alguien te preguntará ¿para qué tienes el Mercedes?